# Windows compresses folder without asking where to put it

Tags: windows-10, compression, zip

When I right-click on a folder I want to compress, then right-click > Send To > Compressed (zipped) Folder, it just starts compressing. It doesn't go through the normal process of asking me what the folder should be called as it usually does, and I don't know where the zipped folder is it's sending to...

How can I make it behave normally again?

Comment: My experience for years is that it always sends to the same folder.  A similar question has been asked here : https://superuser.com/questions/648659/windows-send-to-compressed-zipped-folder-in-different-location .  You may be able to make a new command using the notes at https://www.askvg.com/how-to-restore-missing-compressed-zipped-folder-item-in-send-to-menu-in-windows-xp-and-vista/

Comment: The compressed file is created in the root directory of the folder or file.

Answer (score 2):

**The short explanation:** I needed to refresh the File Explorer Window (Right-click empty space > Refresh).

**The long version:**
Windows was creating the zip folders in the folder I was in, but wasn't showing any of them.

When I opened a new File Explorer Window, and went to the same folder, all the zipped folders were there (I tried to zip the folder a few times to make sure I wasn't crazy). It might be a setting I or my sysadmin set and forgot about because it doesn't do that on my other computer.

I'm not sure when this changed. In the past when I have zipped a folder, it asks where to put the zipped folder, and it shows up immediately.

Comment: When *extracting* you get a window asking where to extract, but I don't remember ever having it ask where to *compress to*....